# putting Mailto: and Tel: into footer.php code wordpress

Tags: php

Can someone explain how I would rewrite this bit of code to include a tel: clickable phone number and make the email address clickable to info:hi.com

I am having a bit of trouble with this.

```
<address class="address_phone">
                                        <span class="icon icon-phone"></span>
                                        <div class="contact_title"><?php echo esc_html__('Phone:', 'yogastudio') ?></div>
                                        <span class="contact_item phone"><?php if (!empty($phone)) echo esc_html($phone); ?></span>
                                        </address></div><div class="column-1_3">
                                    <address class="address_email">
                                        <span class="icon icon-mail"></span>
                                        <div class="contact_title"><?php echo esc_html__('Email:', 'yogastudio') ?></div>
                                        <span class="contact_item mail"><?php if (!empty($email)) echo esc_html($email); ?></span>

                                    </address></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit your code as below:

```
<address class="address_phone">
                                        <span class="icon icon-phone"></span>
                                        <div class="contact_title"><?php echo esc_html__('Phone:', 'yogastudio') ?></div>
                                        <span class="contact_item phone">
                                            <?php if (!empty($phone)) { echo '<a href="tel:'.$phone.'">'.esc_html($phone).'</a>';} ?>
                                        </span>
                                        </address></div><div class="column-1_3">
                                    <address class="address_email">
                                        <span class="icon icon-mail"></span>
                                        <div class="contact_title"><?php echo esc_html__('Email:', 'yogastudio') ?></div>
                                        <span class="contact_item mail"><?php if (!empty($email)) { echo '<a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.esc_html($email).'</a>';}?></span>

                                    </address></div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain how this solves the problem? If the OP ever has to add another `tel:` to their footer they would need to pick apart your code example to figure out what you did

Comment: yes that worked great thanks.  I have another corresponding tel and email in the top panel of the theme which i can't seem to find the code for.  Does work though

Answer (score 1):

Remove.

```
<?php if (!empty($phone)) { echo '<a href="tel:'.$phone.'">'.esc_html($phone).'</a>';} ?>
```

Replace with

```
<a href="tel:+4401234567895">Call us</a>
```

Note you should include the International dial code as well.

For the email, replace

```
<?php if (!empty($email)) { echo '<a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.esc_html($email).'</a>';}?>
```

With:

```
<a href="mailto:youremail@yourdomain.com">Email us</a>
```

Comment: This reads more like an extended comment on @Praktib.Simform's answer than an answer in its own right. Please [edit the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/346272/edit) to answer the original question more fully.

Comment: @PatJ I think this is just a better version of that answer as it's easier to see what the solution is, whereas the other answer is just copy pasta that doesn't explain anything

Comment: I agree, it definitely has better explanations; its advice to "Replace X with Y", though, references X from the other answer, not from the question. (Which, I realize, is kind of nitpicky, but if the other answer gets modified or removed this answer no longer really applies.)